# Outofmemory exception while converting json to list using Gson

Tags: android, json, gson, out-of-memory, jsonconverter

I got outofmemory exception while converting json file to list using Gson

```
Caused by 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Failed to allocate a 18874376 byte 
allocation with 18575992 free 
bytes and 17MB until OOM, target 
footprint 268435456, growth limit 
268435456

@Nullable
public <T> List<T> getConvertedListFromJson(JSONArray jsonArray, Class<T> type) throws OutOfMemoryError{
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    return gson.fromJson(jsonArray.toString(), new ListOf<>(type));

}
```

How to over come this issue

Answer (score 0):

**OutOfMemoryError** usually means that you’re doing something wrong, either holding onto objects too long or trying to process too much data at a time. Sometimes, it indicates a problem that’s out of your control, such as a third-party library that caches strings or an application server that doesn’t clean up after deploys. And sometimes, it has nothing to do with objects on the heap.

Comment: Yes atleast 5000 jsonarray records converted to list using Gson

Comment: Crash occured only in redmi8 mobile

Comment: try to create thread  and use your code there may be OS would have been  blocking something into redmi device

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).